# Tricky MySQL ORDER BY problem

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
id  title               parent_forum    depth
1   'Forum1'             0               0   
2   'Forum2'             0               0   
3   'Forum3'             0               0   
4   'Forum1 subforum'    1               0   
5   'Forum2 subForum'    2               0   
6   'Forum3 subForum'    3               0
```

What I want to do is sort the rows so that all subForums are grouped by their parent forums. So, as an example, I would like the output to be ordered as follows:

```
id  title               parent_forum    depth
1   'Forum1'             0               0
4   'Forum1 subforum'    1               0

2   'Forum2'             0               0  
5   'Forum2 subForum'    2               0
7   'Forum2 subForum2'   2               0

3   'Forum3'             0               0   
6   'Forum3 subForum'    3               0
```

(spaces for better understanding)
There must be a way with just ORDER BY and GROUP BY? If not, can anyone offer a good query to help me out?

EDIT: Or does my database structure just suck (I haven't shown the whole lot, but is the stuff you CAN see rubbish?)

Thanks muchly,

James

Comment: forget to include what sort of ORDER u looking for subForums?

Comment: Can a subforum have an id value that is less than it's parent?

Comment: Possibly, but unlikely - the forums and sub-forums will be added via a form, so the admin could create all the top level forums, THEN the sub forums, so yes. Thanks for the input, but Eric Petroelje has solved this issue in a wonderfully simple way (below) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this aught to do the trick:

```
ORDER BY IF(parent_forum = 0,id,parent_forum), parent_forum
```

Comment: This works a charm - thanks so much! Such a simple answer. I was going to use multiple queries inside a loop, but you've just saved me overhead. It wasn't going to take much, but I need things to be as fast as possible.

Comment: @JamWaffles - If you can have sub-sub forums (beyond just two levels deep) this might not work - I can't quite visualize how that ORDER BY would behave in my head, so you'll want to test for it if that's actually possible in your system.

Comment: This query is just for the top level landing page. Forums below the second level (as in, ones not covered in my OP) will be on a separate page, and I'll be using slightly different queries, taking the depth of the chosen sub forum into account. I'll probably be back with another thread for more help soon! :P